# how to get the HTML Service for addons like on second 30 of this video?

Tags: google-apps-script

in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=30&v=zgSVP9Pd-B4

they show a drag and drop builder for addon interfaces, but when I go to `file > new > html file`

I only get a code editor, not a drag and drop builder.

where to get this view?

Comment: The Apps Script code editor does not integrate with GWT.  To use GWT you need to go through the "Getting Started" steps.  [http://www.gwtproject.org/gettingstarted.html](http://www.gwtproject.org/gettingstarted.html)  They recommend using the Eclipse code editor with GWT.  So, you can't use the drag and drop html builder inside of the Apps Script code editor.  Many people use a different IDE, and then somehow integrate their files into the Apps Script code editor.

Comment: so what editor do you see in this video @SandyGood?

Comment: The very first code editor shown in that video, that has "test.html" at the top; it's not the Apps Script code editor.  There are two code editor's shown in that video. 
 The video is misleading and confusing and was posted in 2012, which is a long time ago in terms of changes in computing.  For information about what people are using for code editors with Apps Script, the best thing to do is ask the question in the Google Apps Script community.  [https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Answer (score 1):

Apps scripts used to have this drag and drop interface to create User Interfaces built into the editor. It was called GUI Builder.

GUI Builder was introduced in 2011 ([Building UI in Apps Script just got a whole lot easier!](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2011/06/building-ui-in-apps-script-just-got.html)) and deprecated in 2013 ([Retiring a Few Apps Script Components](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/retiring-a-few-apps-script-components.html)). Nowadays the only way to create an UI is using `HtmlService`